# How to Delpoy the Hyperledger Composer Rest API to an External IP

Tags: rest, api, config, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I'm trying to find out what config to edit in order to allow my generated Hyperledger Composer Rest API to be able to be hosted on my Ip address instead of Local Host :3000. Ive seen the post referring to 
changing

```
COMPOSER_DATASOURCES='{
"db": {
"name": "db",
"connector": "mongodb",
"host": ""
}
```

But I how no idea where I would define this, or if this even is related to the Rest API hosting address.
General explanations would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Please, rework your request concerning indentation and marking code as code.

Answer (score 0):

The COMPOSER_DATASOURCES configuration is for the host of the Mongo server for persistent storage of Wallets, NOT for the hostname of the REST server itself.

The final line of output for the REST server when it starts is to quote 'localhost', but in reality the REST server is not bound to any particular IP on your machine, so you should be able to hit it on the IP of the machine.